# position absolute footer also follow scrolling

Tags: html, css

We have a footer div with absolute position on the bottom. The parent is overflow `auto`. When you scroll the `.container`,  the `.footer` is also is scrolling. How to make the `.footer` div stay in place.

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  START<br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br />END
  <div class="footer">
    FOOTER
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One small change will make trick:

```css
.footer {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  START<br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br />END
  <div class="footer">
    FOOTER
  </div>
</div>
```

`position: sticky;` acts like mix of fixed and relative: [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

It has good browser support, every major browser supports it (except for IE11 - so all modern major browsers).

Comment: as a sidenote: IE already recieves no further updates and will be deprecated starting at the 17th August 2021 and finished to be deprecated at the 30th November. There is litterally no reason to not use `position: sticky;` to support IE anymore.

Answer (score -1):

The most elegant solution I can find to this problem is setting both the footer and the parent as separate div classes (not parent and child elements). Then, I set both as `position: relative;` with the footer subtracted 20 pixels from its top of 0 pixels. This is to preserve length.

The following is your new code:

```css
.container {
    background-color: red;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.footer {
    position: relative;
    top:-20px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  START<br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br /> 1
  <br />END
</div>

<div class="footer">
  FOOTER
</div>
```

Notice that I changed the width of the footer to match the "container" and the top to -20 pixels to keep the height the same.

Now, if you change the height of the container or move the element around, as long as you apply the same size or positional changes to the footer, it should stay magnetized to the bottom of the container.

Comment: **down-voted for following reason:** technical incorrect and not workign as intended. There is not use to use `position: relative;` twice. `.footer` should be `position: fixed;` in this case. Also your footer is cutting away some of the content (displayed over it). In your snippet you see, that you can scroll down enough to also see the `END` line.